# What are the best minimal windows XP themes you know?

Tags: windows-xp, themes

I'm thinking about changing my plain-old xp theme (classic) into something new, but still minimalistic.

Which ones do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lite Step](http://www.litestep.net/) themes offer a lot of customization. You could probably find a lot of minimalists themes at [customize.org](http://customize.org/litestep).

Examples:
[SimpleDark](http://customize.org/litestep/themes/64254)
[YBoris Minimal Litestep](http://customize.org/litestep/themes/51173)

Answer (score 2):

[Royale Noir](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Themes/Royale-Noir-Theme.shtml)

A great dark theme, very similar to the default classic theme.

Answer (score 1):

[Watercolor Lite](http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t32604.html)

[b0se's Opus Luna](http://b0se.deviantart.com/art/Opus-Luna-1-5-4533528) (and some of his other themes)

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes to black styles.

Easy on the eyes.

- Royale Noir
- Graphite
- Razor black (Vista like)
- Zune (the multi color mods, i don't like an orange start button ;)

All available on deviantArt i believe.